# DalekJS cannot launch Mozilla FF on Windows Server 2k8 x64?

Tags: node.js, dalekjs

I recently came across [DalekJS](http://dalekjs.com/) and decided to try it out.I was able to quickly get through the initial setup and started with the instructions mentioned in the Firefox plug-in [documentation](http://dalekjs.com/docs/firefox.html).

Now here is where things stop working. I always keep getting an error that says "WebDriverServer cannot be launched since the port  is in use".

This happens irrespective of whatever port number i provide in the Dalekfile.

Can someone please help me with this?

My system configuration: Windows server 2008 x64 with the latest version of NodeJS and the most recent dalekJS package installed (0.13). My FF version is 27.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed an issue with the docs of the Firefox plugin, this might raise your error.

Before (wrong):

```
 "browsers": {
   "firefox": {
     "binary": "/Applications/Custom Located Firefox.app/MacOS/Contents/firefox-bin" 
   }
 }
```

After (correct):

```
 "browsers": [{
   "firefox": {
     "binary": "/Applications/Custom Located Firefox.app/MacOS/Contents/firefox-bin" 
   }
 }]
```

Maybe thats all it takes to fix the issue. If not, please open up an issue here: https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek-browser-firefox/issues?state=open